# dynamic jquery ui selectmenu not styling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am using multiple select menu's using http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu .  They work great when initialized with the page but dynamic select menu's do not style and look like normal select tags.
my code..(defquestion is a select box as well with YES/NO options)

```
 $('select').selectmenu({ 
     style: 'popup',
     width: 100
});
$('#defquestion').livequery(function(){
$(this).change(function(){
    var selected = $('#defquestion').val();
    if(selected == 'Yes'){
$('#defresult').append('<p class = "idp">Points allowed = 0:<select id = "pa0"><br><option value = "12">12</option></select><br></p>');
```

I excluded more options tags..but I doubt that is the problem..
Livequery has worked great for other dynamic uses, but not here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure you are closing your tags properly, The code you have is missing this at the end:

```
 }     // close if argument
 });   // close .change()
 });   // close .livequery()
```

If that doesn't solve it, try it without the `livequery`, like this..

```
$('#defquestion').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected == 'Yes'){
        $('#defresult').append('<p class = "idp">Points allowed = 0:<select id = "pa0"><br><option value = "12">12</option></select><br></p>');
    }
});
```